# Label's 'text' property is updating only once in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin

When a specific button is pressed - there is a sequence of 'get' values is performed. Every time the 'get' function is called - it also calls event NotifyPropertyChanged (CreatureBuilder class below) - with this the label's text value is being (should be) changed.

**It works each time the value is changed** but for some reason **it is updated visiually only once on phone** at the end of the sequence

I have label in FightPage.xaml:

```
<Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.RowSpan ="5"
               Grid.Column ="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Text="{Binding EmotionsView}"
               FontSize="4"
               MaxLines="50" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
               CharacterSpacing="10"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               FontFamily="serif"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

Changing it with:

```
private string Emotion; 
    public string EmotionsView
    {
        get
        {
            return Emotion;
        }
        set
        { 
            Emotion = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EmotionsView));
        }
    }
```

'EmotionsView' is being updated when I am getting 'emoji'-value of 'CreatureBuilder' class:

```
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 public String[] getEmotions(short num, bool notify)
    {
        if(notify)
            NotifyPropertyChanged("emotions");
        setlastEmotionReproduced(num);
        return emoji;
    }
```

Subscribing PropertyChanged event in FightPage.xaml.cs when Initializing:

```
public CreatureBuilder cb { get; set; }
public FightPage()
    {
        Title = "Fight Page";
        InitializeComponent();

        var t = Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            while (fight.cb == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an alternative thread to set value...");
                await Task.Delay(25);
            }
        });
        cb = fight.cb;
        cb.PropertyChanged += _OnCBPropertyChanged; //Subscribing
        EmotionsView = "gsdgsgsdgdsggds"; //For test (works)
        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

And the '_OnCBPropertyChanged' function:

```
void _OnCBPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "emotions")
           EmotionsView = ((CreatureBuilder)sender).getEmotions(((CreatureBuilder)sender).getlastEmotionReproduced(),false)[((CreatureBuilder)sender).getlastEmotionReproduced()];
        
    }
```

Edit 1 (Added sequence of *'get's'*). Main thread does the job:

```
public static void RaiseYerHand(ref CreatureBuilder cb, ref CreatureBuilder  cbP)
    {
       // . . . //
        
        string temp = cb.getEmotions(1,true)[1]; //The call
        
        
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        //If enemy died
        if (cb.getHP() < 1)
            return;
        //His turn
        EnemyRaisedABiggerOne(ref cb, ref cbP);
    }
    public static void EnemyRaisedABiggerOne(ref CreatureBuilder cb, ref CreatureBuilder cbP)
    {
        string temp = cb.getEmotions(0,true)[0]; //The call
        Thread.Sleep(400);

        temp = cb.getEmotions(2,true)[2]; //The call
//. . . //
            //Other Logic //
//. . . //
        temp = cb.getEmotions(3,true)[3]; //The call
        Thread.Sleep(1100);

    }
```

Comment: where is the "sequence of get values" that causes this problem?

Comment: @Jason, added to the question

Comment: Sorry,I can't quite understand your code because of the  scattered code and  there are no relevant comments. If it is convinient for you,could you please post the full code of your viewmodel and current page?

Comment: Update of UI should be invoked on main thread.. BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => update)